# how i can give a variable for this list

Tags: python-2.7

i have list like this

```
http://google.com:username:password
http://google2.com:username2:password2
```

how i can give a variable for this list i went give 3 variable Address , username , password

when i do print Address i went this program print for me google.com

and when i do print username i went this program print for me username

Comment: `Address = "http://google.com:username:password"`

Comment: Do you want something like a key and a value, if so use dictionary ! where you can give keys as address,username and password and related values to these keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the most straightforward solution may be to put your list into a python [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) structure with your 3 variables as `keys`, and each `key` is associated with individual `values`:

```
mydict = [
        {
            'Address': 'http://google.com',
            'username': 'username',
            'password': 'password'
            },

       {
            'Address': 'http://google2.com:username2:password2',
            'username': 'username2',
            'password': 'password2'
            }
       ]
```

Demo:
We have 2 entries from the original list, so you can specify which entry you want by indexing the dictionary starting from `0` as the first entry

```
# access 1st entry values
print mydict[0]['Address']  # http://google.com
print mydict[0]['username'] # username

# access 2nd entry values
print mydict[1]['password'] # password2
```